# Set C++ as the default syntax highlighter for the [systemc] tag

Tags: feature-request, tags, syntax-highlighting

Please set the syntax highlighting language used by the [systemc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/systemc) tag to be the same as the [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) tag.

Currently, [systemc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/systemc) does not have syntax highlighting, but [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) does.  The [systemc tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/systemc/info) aptly states that "SystemC is a collection C++ classes and macros".  Thus, it makes sense for [systemc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/systemc) to use the same highlighting as [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b): `lang-cpp`.

Several questions are tagged with both, and the highlighting looks fine. For example, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35425052/how-to-initialize-a-systemc-port-name-which-is-an-array).

There are currently 266 [systemc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/systemc) questions total, and 156 do not have the [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) tag.  I think it would be beneficial for these posts to have highlighted code.  Some [systemc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/systemc) questions do not require the [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) tag as well since they address features that are unique to the class library itself, and not to [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) in general.  [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62494341/member-of-b-object-cant-write-in-systemc) is one such example.

Comment: When would you ever use the systemc tag without c++?

Comment: @Makoto: There are currently 266 `systemc` questions total, and 156 do not have the `c++` tag.  I haven't posted any of these questions, so I don't know why others would do that.

Comment: I'm referring more to "you" in the hypothetical here. Are there valid reasons why people would ask a question in regards to *just* the framework and not the language, similar to how people don't tend to ask a Spring question without asking about either Java or Kotlin?

Comment: @Makoto: Yes, the framework angle.  I updated my question.

Comment: I'm fuzzy on the highlighting rules as they relate to tags, but it's definitely weird that the second question you linked doesn't seem to highlight at all, not even with a guess... I don't know why that is exactly. I _assume_ setting the language on the tag would solve it, but I'm also not sure whether it would mess up the ones tagged with c++ too. I recall the rules being really odd.

Comment: Things like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69171109/cross-compiling-systemc-libraries-and-linking-to-them) shouldn't necessarily be entirely highlighted as C++, as only one of the code blocks is actually C++. Aside from that, I think it is reasonable, as Makoto already said, to demand that all such questions about the C++ language be tagged as [[tag:c++]], making this hinting unnecessary.